# Cellular signal handoff

Tags: switching

In a cellular network like T-Mobile, Sprint, etc. if one sector of a tri-sector tower is maxed out and can't accept new calls, will a new call request normally served in that sector be handed off to another sector (or another tower/sector) with the next best received signal strength? Or will the call be blocked?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, a lot of this depends on the configuration adopted by each carrier.
 Having said that, most carriers will try to hand the call off to another tower or another contracted carrier. Dropped calls are something to be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on user location. If user moves in the central location of utilized sector call will dropped till free channel receive. If user moves at border of covered area by utilized sector then call handover. Nowadays, calls are matured by using roaming networks like other cellular operator as UE are very smart.